# How can i let the oozie workflow run after killing the coordinator?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, oozie-coordinator

I've been working with oozie for a while, I wanted to kill a coordinator but I don't want to kill the workflow that's being kicked off by the coordinator.

Why do I want to do that? I have a scenario where my job has to run once every 15minutes but the first job took more than 3 hours because of the historical data that's being loaded in the currently running instance and because of that rest of the jobs piled up. Below picture is an example of that.

[Oozie Snapshot for the explained question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edxYm.png)

Thanks in Advance, feel free to ask for any other information required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of killing the coordinator, just suspend it.
If the coordinator is suspended, the workflow will be suspended as well, but you can resume the workflow.
After the first big workflow is done, you can resume the coordinator so it keeps scheduling workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You could update endTime of the coordinator to the current time. Then the coordinator will be gracefully ended with "SUCCEEDED" as status, while its corresponding workflow will still running until it’s finished.
`<oozie_endpoint>/oozie/v2/job/<coord_id>?action=change&value=endtime=<current_time>`